# Active Directory not finding all users in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have some code that queries Active Directory to verify user existence.  I am trying to verify a long list of about 1300 ids.  I've tried several methods to verify if a user account (LINQ to AD, DirectorySearcher (with and without a parent DirectoryEntry) and also a DirectoryEntry that links to the WinNT:// path).  Every time it will come back and say that several users do not exist.  If I hardcode their userids in the code and execute for individually, it validates existence.  If I try and do it in a foreach loop, I get several false negatives.

Here's the code I am using right now..

```
static string[] userIDs = new string[] "user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7","user8"...,"user1300"};

List<string> nonExistingUsers = new List<string>();
List<string> ExistingUsers = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in userIDs)
{
 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
 search.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", s);
 search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
 DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=" + s + "))", new string[] { "Name" }, SearchScope.Subtree);
 SearchResultCollection resultCollection = ds.FindAll();
 SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
 if (result != null)
  ExistingUsers.Add(s);
 else
  nonExistingUsers.Add(s);
}
```

Any suggestions or reasons why I am getting the false negatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

- first of all, try using the "anr=" (ambiguous name resolution) in your LDAP filter - it searches several name-related attributes and make searching easier. The UserID might not be part of the actual "common name" (CN=user1)
- secondly, use the objectCategory instead of objectClass - the objectCategory is single-valued and indexed and thus a fair bit faster on searches
- thirdly: why are you first calling .FindAll() and then .FindOne() on the next line? Doesn't seem really necessary at all....
- WinNT:// really is only for backward compatibility and if you need to deal with local computer accounts - try to avoid it whenever possible, it also exposes a lot less properties than LDAP

Here's my code I'd write:

```
static string[] userIDs = new string[] "user1","user2","user3","user4","user5","user6","user7","user8"...,"user1300"};

DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=Users,dc=YourComp,dc=com");

List<string> nonExistingUsers = new List<string>();
List<string> ExistingUsers = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in userIDs)
{
   DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

   search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
   search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(anr={0}))", s);

   SearchResultCollection resultCollection = ds.FindAll();

   if(resultCollection != null && resultCollection.Count > 0)
      ExistingUsers.Add(s);
   else
      nonExistingUsers.Add(s);
}
```

Does that work in your scenario??

Also, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, things got a lot easier - see:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)